# Flutter Execution failed for task ':webview_flutter:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, flutter, androidx

I cannot build after updating flutter and andriodX. I keep gettng the error below with a lots of warning messages. I upgraged flutter. I also executed flutter doctor. It has not helped.
The app was working fine and in order to user Firebase authentication,I created SHA1. After that it stopped working. Please suggest. I have looked over all other similar questions but I can't seem to find a solution.

```
Note: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core_web-0.1.1+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase_core_web\FirebaseCoreWebPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.7+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\SharedPreferencesPlugin.java:18: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
      public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {                                                       ^
    1 warning
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\webviewflutter\InputAwareWebView.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
      private ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView proxyAdapterView;
              ^
      symbol:   class ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView
      location: class InputAwareWebView
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\webviewflutter\InputAwareWebView.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
            new ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView(
                ^
      symbol:   class ThreadedInputConnectionProxyAdapterView
      location: class InputAwareWebView
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    2 errors
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':webview_flutter:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    
    * Try:
            
    BUILD FAILED in 2m 22s
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

gradle.properties

```
  android.useAndroidX=true
  android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Hi, it seems your webview_flutter plugin is having some version issues after you upgraded. Please add some relevant codes to your post.

Comment: I had webview_flutter in my code and pubspec.yaml , but I removed it completely. Not sure why its still giving this error. What code would you want me to add, please tell.